# Merge Request: [visual-studio-code] and [vscode]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

I would like to propose making [vscode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vscode) a synonym of [visual-studio-code](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

Questions regarding Visual Studio Code are actively posted under both the [visual-studio-code](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) and [vscode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vscode) tags. There is no difference between the usage of these tags.

- [visual-studio-code](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) - "Visual Studio Code is a cross-platform source code editor from Microsoft."
- [vscode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vscode) - "Visual Studio Code is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and macOS."

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure where you are getting that from. The visual-studio-code and vscode tags are both clearly referring to the VSCode application.

Comment: Yes, that's clear from usage. I think these tags should be merged too. This needn't have been synonymous given how many things out there carry the name visual studio, for example, visual basic studio et cetera.

Comment: @Nick Both tags are referring to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) specifically.

Comment: @Nick please refer to [Visual Studio's official site](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), Visual Studio IDE and Visual Studio Code are different products. I'm not sure what you are referring to Visual Basic Studio because Visual Basic and C# are programming languages, but Visual Studio IDE and Visual Studio Code are applications.

Comment: Very apt request! Makes perfect sense to merge these two tags. Thanks for raising this.

Comment: @Nick "Visual Basic Studio" do you mean Visual Basic 6? Visual Basic Express (prior to 2012 / the "community" builds, Microsoft released language specific versions of visual studio for free)? Those are the only "Visual Basic" specific IDEs that I know of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Agree, this is done

```
A tag synonym mapping vscode → visual-studio-code will be created.



updating post history, 120 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 117 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 100 rows affected
destroying 'vscode': [vscode] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 198
tag remapping of [visual-studio-code] and [vscode] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
10 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
22 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```